# Calling user defined JavaScript function inside ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I wrote my own JavaScript function inside an ejs file which I want to use it inside that file. The problem is that it is not working because the function is declared to be undefined .
I have declared that function inside the ejs file as illustrated below.

```
//my ejs file
<script> 
        function c_tab (){
            //codes...
            return "data";
         }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME  TO  E J S </h1>
     <p>Ok this willrecievedata from server ... <%=  c_tab(); %> 
    </p>
```

The  error report says that  **c_tab is not defined**

**So how to use a user defined javascript  function inside ejs file .**

Answer (score 1):

Well, the basic answer to your question is probably

```
<%
    var foo = function(){return 'bar'};
%>
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME  TO  E J S </h1>
     <p>Ok this will recieve data from server ... <%=  foo(); %> 
    </p>
</body>
```

but since you said "receive data from the server" in your code, I presume you are passing local variables from express to ejs via `.render()`

In that case the variables should just be *available*, but you want them available in your client side code. Try something like

```
<script>
  var foo = <%= JSON.stringify(bar_obj_from_server)%>
  var fooString = '<%= bar_str_from_server %>'
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Scriptlet tag instead of script tag:

```
<% 
        function c_tab (){
            //codes...
            return "data";
        }
%>
```